# Campos obligatorios con base a un RadioButtom

Tags: javascript, java, jsf, primefaces

Hola estoy haciendo un sistema en el cual asigno un aprobador a un proyecto pero no es obligatorio asignar un aprobador por eso lo hago por medio de un radionButtom, si la persona selecciona SI se desglosan tres campos y si es NO se ocultan esos campos eso ya logre hacerlo, pero el problema es que cuando la selección del radioButtom sean Si quiero que los tres campos que se desglosan sean obligatorios y si es No no sean obligatorios.

Ojala alguien pueda ayudarme, anexo el código.

```
                                <div class="form-group input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">Asignar Aprobador: </span>
                                <p:selectOneRadio class="form-control" onclick="show(this.value)" value="#{projectsBean.proyectos.approver}" >
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Si"  itemValue="Si"/>
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="No"  itemValue="No" >
                                    </f:selectItem>

                                </p:selectOneRadio>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group input-group" style="display:none"  id="ar">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">* Área del aprobador: </span>
                                <h:selectOneMenu class="form-control" id="area"  value="#{projectsBean.area}" requiredMessage="* Obligatorio - Área">
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="-- Seleccionar --" itemValue="#{null}"/>
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{loginBean.listAreas}"/>
                                    <f:ajax execute="area" render="role"/>
                                </h:selectOneMenu>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group input-group" style="display:none" id="rol">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">* Rol del aprobador: </span>
                                <h:selectOneMenu class="form-control" id="role"  value="#{projectsBean.rol}" requiredMessage="* Obligatorio - Rol">
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="-- Seleccionar --" itemValue="#{null}"/>
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{projectsBean.listRol}"/>
                                    <f:ajax execute="role" render="perso"/>
                                </h:selectOneMenu>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group input-group" style="display:none" id="per">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">* Nombre del aprobador </span>
                                <h:selectOneMenu class="form-control" id="perso" value="#{projectsBean.aprovador}" requiredMessage="* Obligatorio - Nombre de la Persona">
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="-- Seleccionar --" itemValue="#{null}"/>
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{projectsBean.listEmpleado}"/>
                                </h:selectOneMenu>
                            </div>
```

Este es el script que muestra y oculta los campos

```
          <script type="text/javascript">

            function show(type) {
                switch (type) {
                    case 'No' :
                        document.getElementById("ar").style.display = "none";                  
                        document.getElementById("rol").style.display = "none";
                        document.getElementById("per").style.display = "none";
                        break;
                    case 'Si' :
                        document.getElementById("ar").style.display = "block";
                        document.getElementById("rol").style.display = "block";
                        document.getElementById("per").style.display = "block";

                        break;
                }
            }

        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Cuando los ocultas o haces aparecer, hay que quitarle/agregarle el atributo `required`

```
  function show(type) {
            switch (type) {
                case 'No' :
                    document.getElementById("ar").style.display = "none"; 
                    document.getElementById("ar").required = false;
                    document.getElementById("rol").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("rol").required = false;
                    document.getElementById("per").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("per").required = false;

                    break;
                case 'Si' :
                    document.getElementById("ar").style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById("ar").required = true;
                    document.getElementById("rol").style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById("rol").required = true;
                    document.getElementById("per").style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById("per").required = true;

                    break;
            }
        }
```

> Fuente: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_required.asp